# Register COM reference to 64-bit Windows 7 machine

Tags: com

I am writing a C# program that interface with COM object through COM interop.

I have a third-party program that register itself as the COM server when I execute the Application. This works fine in 32-bit Windows Vista and I can interface with the interop just fine. (The reference show up in "COM" tab from Visual Studio when you click "Add Reference")

However, the reference does not show up in "COM" tab on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine after I execute the application. Any thoughts, why would this happen? I actually tried using regsvr32.exe to register the application manually but it didn't work either (error message saying "entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to use it as long as it doesn't show up in the COM tab.  The regsvr32.exe utility is for DLLs, this however sounds like an EXE.  If it is a DLL then it needs to be registered with the 32-bit version of regsvr32.exe, the one in c:\windows\syswow64.  If it is an EXE then the normal way to get it to register itself is by running it with the /regserver command line option.

> Mumble.exe /RegServer

Additionally, if this is a DLL or an EXE for which you don't have a 64-bit proxy/stub then you'll have to force your app to run in 32-bit mode.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = x86.

If all else fails, you really *do* need support from the vendor of this program.  Surely they'll have an update available that is verified to work properly on 64-bit operating systems.  If they are no longer around, running this in a virtual machine is always a possibility.

Comment: Thank you very Hans, this is very helpful. The file I was trying to register is actually .exe, no wonder I couldn't do it. I did already set the Platform target = x86. Where is Mumble.exe located? How do I get it?

Comment: I can't help you find the .exe, don't you already know?  It's the 3rd party program you mention in your OP.

Comment: Oh sorry, I probably misunderstood you. I thought you mentioned about a tool called Mumble.exe -- it's probably just yr example. Of course I would know where that 3rd party program is located.

Comment: I'll call it Foo.exe next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a managed dll then you might try using RegAsm

```
REGASM AssemblyName.dll /tlb:AssemblyName.tlb
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful as I needed to recompiled and build 64 bit proxy stub for the COM server from C++ myself and it kept failing when trying to register the server using /regserver. Here is and thread from miscrosoft that helped me resolved this issue. Basically you need to use this instead  /RegServerPerUser, but go through the thread if you get into this situation after the answers from above.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcprerelease/thread/11f01ceb-52a4-438f-b7ef-727ce7a3e191